# Как в цикле wordpress вывести несколько постов вместе с несколькими тегами без дублей?

Tags: php, wordpress

Когда пытаюсь вывести в цикле посты с несколькими тегами посты дублируются. При этом если вывродим внтури категории пост с 1 тегом, то все норм. Где я не прав? Пробовал циклы менять местами, закрывать циклы чтобы было 2 endforeach на каждый цикл, тогда вообще не работает.
Надо чтобы, если у поста внтури категории больше одного тега выводился только один пост.Сейчас если 2 тега у поста выводятся 2 одинаковых поста.
Прим. На странице 5 табов. Внтури табов +/- одинаковый код только разница с тем из какой категории выводятся посты.

````
//Получаем посты из категории 4 по 4 поста  
<?php $posts = get_posts ("category=4&orderby=date&numberposts=4"); ?> 
<?php if ($posts) : ?>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata ($post); ?>
//Получаем теги для поста
<?php $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
//Выводим ссылки на теги
    $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);?>           
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 off-pd line-item">
                <div class="prod-card">
    <a href="<?php echo $tag_link; ?>">
//и картинку поста 
 <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium'); ?>" class="product-img img-responsive" ></a>
                    <div class="product-discr">
                        <p class="product-h"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                        <p class="product-short"><?php the_field('short_diskr_post') ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             <?php
}
?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>```
````

Comment: Наверное потому что [wp_get_post_tags()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_post_tags) получает список меток указанного поста в виде массива, а Вы вместо того чтобы просто в цикле прокрутить `<a href="<?php echo $tag_link; ?>">` если замысел в том чтобы вывести метки в карточке записи, прокручиваете в цикле весь пост, что не имеет смысла, конечно он будет дублироваться, если там больше одной метки.

Comment: Можете подсказать, как должно быть написанно,?А то в пхп не оч силен. Замысл в том чтобы выводить посты с метками внутри категории. Если соответсенно у поста 2 сетки он тоже должен бытьв категории, но уж никак не 2 поста.

Comment: Что-то вроде такого: `<?php foreach ($tags as $tag) : ?><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_tag_link($tag->term_id)); ?>"><?php  endforeach; ?>`. Желательно проверить перед этим всем, не пустой ли массив `$tags`.

Comment: Задумывалось, что при клике на изображени поста пользователь бы попадал на старницу тегов этого постав. поэтому там     <a href="<?php echo $tag_link; ?>"> Это /дубль постов все ещё не оч понятно.

Comment: Получайте первый тег из массива или по ключу или через [array_shift()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php). У меня там ошибка, потому что я только открывающий `a` засунул в цикл и не сопоставил с тем что у Вас внутри табнейл. `Это /дубль постов все ещё не оч понятно.` -- если у поста 2 тега, то так как внутри цикла вся карточка поста, то логично что он выведется два раза, так как тега два и цикл отпработает два раза.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ладно, может я не совсем понимаю что Вам нужно. По клику на изображение, чтобы пользователь попадал на страницу метки, не слишком очевидное поведение. Но ок, можете получить самый первый тег из массива тегов используя `$tags[0]`, ну и потом получаете ссылку на тег, если он есть.

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts("category=4&orderby=date&numberposts=4");
if ($posts) :
    foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata ($post);
        $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
        // Получаем первый тег для поста
        $tag = $tags[0] ?? false;
?>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 off-pd line-item">
            <div class="prod-card">
                <?php if ($tag) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_tag_link($tag->term_id)); ?>">
                <?php endif; ?>
                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium'); ?>" class="product-img img-responsive" >
                <?php if ($tag) : ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="product-discr">
                    <p class="product-h"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                    <p class="product-short"><?php the_field('short_diskr_post') ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Как планировалось Есть старница Тег.пхп. Там динамический заголовок, в зависимости от тега. Туда пользователь попадает если кликает на картинку с постом. Я хз зачем, да не очевидно. Я согласен. Но на этой же странице отражаюся все посты данной метки. Если на примере. Посты про краски -щёлкнул на картинку и попадает на страницу тегов где все посты про краски. По этой логике если у поста первый тег задан условно бобры то пользователь попалдёт на страницу бобры. Потому что первый тег - бобры. правильно?

Comment: @SolomonFox да, верно. Просто тут минус в том, что Вы так не сможете вывести все теги поста.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь. Что значит не смогу вывести все теги поста? Судя по коду нет ограничений на теги. Мне нужно было чтобы можно было без ограничений присваивать теги к постам и они отражались в нужной группе. И при этом работал динамический заголовок. Все есть. Можно подробнее про минус пожалуйста.

Comment: @SolomonFox ну так как Вы оборачиваете табнейл в ссылку на тег, то если у записи будет два тега, Вы же не будете два раза выводить табнейл, верно? Ну то есть, тегов Вы посту можете хоть сотню присвоить, но ссылка то у Вас одна, в данном случае.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что весь минус что мы обращаемя именно к первому тегу и только его можем вывести. Т.е. нет гибкости и всегда будем обращаться к первому тегу? Если так то все норм. Я как раз не знал, как отразить множестову тегов на одной странице вместе с динамическим заголовком.  Подскажите будет браться первый тег по времени создания? Или по ИД? как считается первенство и можно ли его изменить?

Comment: @SolomonFox да, все верно. По-умолчанию вроде как по имени, изменить можно, передав вторым параметром массив аргументов, посмотреть какие аргументы можно передать, можете [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_object_terms) (это другая функция, но параметры те же, так как [оригинальная функция](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_post_tags) для аргументов ссылается на ту ссылку что я Вам предоставил).

Comment: Вроде все посмотрел, но так и не понял, как он именно опредлеяет какой тег первый, по моим предположениям по времени создания. Т.е. какой раньше создали тот и первый.

Comment: @SolomonFox По [ссылке](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_object_terms) пролистываете до понкта `$args` - Переписывает аргументы по умолчанию. Весь список аргументов смотрите в описании функции [wp_get_object_terms()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_object_terms). Переходите по ссылке на `wp_get_object_terms()` и листаете до `$args` там будет пункт `orderby` и там написано: `name - по имени. По умолчанию.` -- что значит что по умолчанию выводится по имени.

Comment: По имени я так понимаю по алфавиту в нашем случае кириличнскому, верно? Если хоти сменить  0 тег (с которого начитается вывод, нужно сменить имя, которое начинается на другую букву из афавита?

Comment: @SolomonFox да, с кириллицей это работает в том числе. Но смена имени, выглядит не совсем универсально. Чем Вас не устраивает вывести список меток под табнейлом?

Comment: Заказчик хочет чтобы при клике на картинку товара (поста) пользователь попадал бы на страницу тегов этого поста. В заголовке страницы функция которая выводит заголовк выбьранной метки.  Никуда за4казчик не хочет выводить метки чтобы клиент ориентировался по ним. Я так подробно справшивал про главную метку чтобы понять как объяснить заказчику как он может настроить главную метку т.е.п ри необходимости смерить.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Если тебя где-то надо лайкнуть или карму поднять. Пиши я сделаю. У меня периодически бывают заказы, когда сам не могу сделать. Можешь оставить контакты? Подкину тебе работу, если сойдемся по бюджету.